# BASH script: How to assign each line of command output to values in an array?

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

When running a command, I get 10 lines of output. I want to take lines 2-4-6-8-10 and put them into an array.

Every time I run my command, the order changes so I need to do this in one go. I had tried running my command and picking out line 2, then running again and picking out line 4 etc., but because the order changes this does not work:

```
value1=$(my_command |sed '2q;d')
value2=$(my_command |sed '4q;d')
value3=$(my_command |sed '6q;d')
value4=$(my_command |sed '8q;d')
value5=$(my_command |sed '10q;d')

MY_ARRAY=("${value1}" "${value2}" "${value3}" "${value4}" "${value5}")
```

Comment: So is your question about how to read command output into an array - or about how to filter alternate lines of output? Which shell are you using?

Comment: sorry, its is a bash script. 
My questions is how do i read every other line of command output into an array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `readarray` in the `bash` shell, and GNU `sed`:

```bash
readarray -t my_array < <( my_command | sed '1~2d' )
```

The built-in `readarray` reads the lines into an array.  The lines are read from a process substitution.  The `sed` command in the process substitution will only  output every second line read from `my_command` (and could also be written `sed '1!n;d'`, or as `sed -n 'n;p'` with standard `sed`).

In GNU `sed`, the address `n~m` addresses every `m`:th line starting at line `n`.  This is a GNU extension to standard `sed`, for convenience.

The `my_command` command will only ever be called once.

Testing:

```
$ readarray -t my_array < <( seq 10 | sed '1~2d' )
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: I am using creating a bash script that requires this code.
I cant get past a syntax error near unexpected token `<'
my code is:
 readarray -t MY_ARRAY < < ( my_command | sed -n '2~2p')
on cmd line my_command | sed -n '2~2p' works as i would hope.

Comment: @a.smith Make sure that `<(...)` does not have a space between `<` and the `(`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.
readarray -t MY_ARRAY < <(echo file.txt | sed -n '2~2p')

my command is not an echo of a file but trying to add more context.

Comment: the shebang at the top of my scrip is #!/bin/bash but i execute my script with sh my_script.sh -  im not to sure of the in's and out's here but i think the problem is im executing with sh. is there an equivalent for sh ?

Comment: @a.smith When you use `sh my_script.sh`, the shebang line is not having any effect. If your script uses `bash` features that `sh` does not understand, such as process substitutions, then don't use `sh` to execute the script. Use `bash`, or make your script executable (`chmod +x my_script.sh`) and run it without an explicit interpreter (`./my_script.sh`).